# Constantly sending data from tableview to tableview cell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, avfoundation, nstimer, avaudioplayer

I have an `NSObject` class that has an `AVAudioPlayer` and an `NSTimer` that I'm using within my view controller that contains my `tableview`.  When I tap on a cell the `AVAudioPlayer` is used to play an audio file associated with the cell and the `NSTimer` is initiated.  What I'm trying to do is send the value for my progress variable (float), which is equal to the currentTime of the audio player divided by the duration of the audio file, back to my custom tableview cell to update the progress bar.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Recording * recording = [self.fetchCon objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL * audioURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:recording.audioURL];
    self.audioPlayer = [[OSTablePlayerController alloc] init];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
    [self.audioPlayer playAudio:data];

    self.audioPlayer.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.audioPlayer.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

 - (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    NSTimeInterval playTime = [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self.audioPlayer duration];

    float progress =  playTime/duration;

    //send progress variable to tableview cell class

    if(!(self.audioPlayer.player.playing))
    {
        [self audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:self.audioPlayer.player successfully:YES];

        progress = 0.00;

        //send progress variable to tableview cell class

    }
}

-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if(flag)
    {
        [self.audioPlayer.timer invalidate];
        self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the cell like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   /* further code to set up the timer etc...*/
}
```

One alternative is to cache the currently selected cell and update the progress value on the cell.

I would, however, recommend that you create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. In the subclass you then have a method for plays the audio content and starts the timer. The cell itself would now observe the progress of the timer. Please note that if you subclass `UITableViewCell` you probably want to implement `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: Hey Lev, I currently have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that controls the play/pause functionality and contains the `NSTimer`.  I figured it would be best to have the timer within the actual view controller with the tableview just to keep my tableview cell as dumb as possible (I was told that this is the proper way of doing it).  With my current set up, when I tap on a cell the progress bar will begin updating.  However, if I scroll while the cell is playing, the reused cell will have its progress bar updating as well...

Comment: I think you need to create a new progress bar in your `prepareForReuse` method. Personally I am not a fan of keeping the cells dumb as I find it often overloads the responsibility of the table or collection view controller. I do, however, not think there is a proper way of doing it. You should exercise some judgement about what is it the easiest way to get your app to do what you want it to.

Comment: Sounds good.  I know when I scroll down, I can clear the progress bar of the reused cell by invalidating the timer and setting progress to zero in prepareForReuse.  But if I scroll back up to the cell that was selected, how do I restart the timer and set its progress to where it should be?

Comment: You could implement the UITableViewDelegate method tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: and check if the indexPath is equal to the currently selected indexPath (you may need to include an instance variable that saves the selected indexPath).  If it is the correct indexPath then fire up your NSTimer again to start updating the cell's progress value.